# NSIS - Get command line argument and store it in a text file

Tags: nsis, electron-builder

I build an app in electron and making exe using electron-builder. I need a URL field during installation so I wrote a script that ask for URL field and store it in a *credentials.txt* file.
**Installing manually(double clicking) is working fine.**
[image]

Now what I want to achieve is, install exe using command line and pass URL as parameter and create credentials.txt and store URL value in it.

```
setup.exe /S /URL="https://hello.com"
```

Here is the script

```html
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

XPStyle on

Var Dialog
Var AppURL
Var URLText
Var URLState
Var URL

Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave

Function nsDialogsPage

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "App URL:"
    Pop $AppURL

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u $URLState
    Pop $URLText

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageLeave

    ${NSD_GetText} $URLText $URLState

    ${If} $URLState == ""
        MessageBox MB_OK "App URL is missing."
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    StrCpy $1 $URLState

    ${GetParameters} $0
    ${GetOptions} "$0" "/URL=" $URL   ////HERE I'm trying to get argument

    ${If} $URL != ""
        StrCpy $1 "$URL"             /// HERE trying to copy $URL value
    ${EndIf}

    FileOpen $9 $INSTDIR\credentials.txt w
    FileWrite $9 "$1"
    FileClose $9
    SetFileAttributes $INSTDIR\credentials.txt HIDDEN|READONLY

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only .onInit and Sections are executed in silent installers, not the pages.

```
Var URL

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh

Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page InstFiles

Function .onInit
${GetParameters} $0
${GetOptions} "$0" "/URL=" $URL
; If the URL is required, check IfSilent and abort if empty here
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u "$URL"
Pop $1
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $1 $URL
${If} $URL == ""
    MessageBox MB_OK "App URL is missing."
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
DetailPrint "TODO: Write $URL to a file here..."
SectionEnd
```

Comment: @Andres Tried above script but throws error while packaging app Error: `Function named ".onInit" already exists.`

Comment: Then put that code inside your existing .onInit.

Comment: Sir, I haven't used any `".onInit"`. What I did now accessed arguments in section block and creating txt file solved my problem. Thanks alot

Comment: If you did not use .onInit then some .nsh you are using does.